# How can I get a curved arrow to break?

Tags: xy-pic

I have the following diagram in `xypic`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,2cell]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[\xymatrix{
& K\Omega M \ar[rr] \ar[ld]_(.4){K\Omega F} \ar@{.>}'[d][dd]_-\simeq  &&  K\Delta M \ar[rr] \ar[ld]  && Kq\Delta M \ar[ld]  \\
K\Omega N \ar[rr] \ar@{.>}[dd]_-\simeq  &&  K\Delta N \ar[rr]  &&  Kq\Delta N  \\
& \Omega Kq\Delta M \ar@/_2pc/[rruu] \ar[ld]_-{\Omega Kq\Delta F} & \\
\Omega Kq\Delta N \ar@/_2pc/[rruu]
}\]

\end{document}
```

This renders like this:

[image]

The curved arrow "on the background" should be broken twice, each time it crosses another arrow, to give the impression of really being in the background. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please complete your code in order to give us a fully compilable version of your posted image. We can then help much quicker and with less work on our side. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Sorry, I tend fo forget about it. Done.

Comment: Maybe you should guide both arrows through "1 element right" and "two elements right and 1 element up". You can then use the `'[d]` trick, you used in element 2-2 as well. If this does not work, you will have to read about knots http://lf.starlogik.de/XYPic-Knot-Intro/node2.html .

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work right, possibly because the arrows are curved.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it can be done with xypic, but just for reference (and for fun) I did it with Tikz.

In this case, the trick is to draw the line which is "in front", twice. The first time is drawn in white and very thick, and the second one in black and at normal width.

Note that in TikZ you first draw the matrix of nodes, using a syntax similar to xy-pic, and then you draw all connections, using as coordinates the names of the nodes of the matrix, which have the general form `(M-row-column)`, and label the required connections using `node`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, row sep=1cm, column sep=0.5cm] (M) {
   & K\Omega M  &&  K\Delta M  && Kq\Delta M   \\
K\Omega N  &&  K\Delta N  &&  Kq\Delta N  \\
   & \Omega Kq\Delta M  & \\
\Omega Kq\Delta N \\
};
\draw[->] (M-1-2) -- (M-2-1) 
   node[midway, above left] {\scriptsize $K\Omega F$};
\draw[->,dotted] (M-2-1) -- (M-4-1)
   node[midway, left] {\scriptsize $\simeq$};
\draw[->] (M-3-2) -- (M-4-1)
   node[midway, above, xshift=-1em] {\scriptsize $\Omega Kq\Delta F$};
\draw[->, dotted] (M-1-2) -- (M-3-2)
   node[pos=0.7, left] {\scriptsize $\simeq$};
\draw[->] (M-1-2) -- (M-1-4);
\draw[->] (M-1-4) -- (M-1-6);
\draw[->] (M-3-2) to[out=20, in=-110] (M-1-4);
\draw[white, line width=1ex] (M-2-1) -- (M-2-3);
\draw[->] (M-2-1) -- (M-2-3);
\draw[white, line width=1ex] (M-2-3) -- (M-2-5);
\draw[->] (M-2-3) -- (M-2-5);
\draw[white, line width=.5ex] (M-4-1) to[out=20, in=-110] (M-2-3);
\draw[->] (M-4-1) to[out=20, in=-110] (M-2-3);
\draw[->] (M-1-4) -- (M-2-3);
\draw[->] (M-1-6) -- (M-2-5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, the result is nice. I would like how to do it with `xypic` though, especially since this is only a small part of a bigger diagram...

Answer (score 3):

This is still not `xypic`, but the syntax of `tikz-cd` is very similar to it. Maybe you can switch to this package for your whole diagram. I would recommend the use of `tikz-cd` as it gives you much more possibilities.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
& K\Omega M \ar{rr} \ar[swap, "K\Omega F"]{dl} \ar[dotted, near end, swap, "\simeq"]{dd}  &&  K\Delta M \ar{rr} \ar{dl} \ar[bend left, <-]{ddll}  && Kq\Delta M \ar{dl}  \\
K\Omega N \ar[crossing over]{rr} \ar[dotted, swap, "\simeq"]{dd} & &  K\Delta N \ar[crossing over]{rr}  &&  Kq\Delta N  \\
& \Omega Kq\Delta M \ar[swap, near start, "\Omega Kq\Delta F"]{dl} & \\
\Omega Kq\Delta N \ar[crossing over, bend right]{uurr}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]